# Cubic equation, got the answer but not sure

Tags: linear-algebra

Cubic equation: $$y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$
through points P(-2, 2), Q(-1.4, 1.2), R(2, -2), S(1.4, -1.2)

a) Find the linear equation that represents the problem above

b) Determine coefficient a, b, c, and d

My answer:

**a)**$$P(-2, 2)  \to y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$
$$2 = a(-2)^3+b(-2)^2+c(-2) + d$$
$$2=-8a+4b-2c+d$$
$$Q(-1.4, 1.2)  \to y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$
$$1.2 = a(-1.4)^3+b(-1.4)^2+c(-1.4) + d$$
$$1.2 = -2.744a+1.96b-1.4c+d$$
$$R(2, -2)  \to y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$
$$-2 = a(2)^3+b(2)^2+c(2) + d$$
$$-2 = 8a+4b+2c+d$$
$$S(1.4, -1.2) \to y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$
$$-1.2 = a(1.4)^3+b(1.4)^2+c(1.4)+d$$
$$-1.2 = 2.744a + 1.96b+1.4c+d$$

**b)**
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  -8&4&-2&1&2\\
  -2.744&1.96&-1.4&1&1.2\\
8&4&2&1&-2\\
2.744&1.96&1.4&1&-1.2
\end{array}
\right] $$
$$X=\begin{bmatrix}\cfrac{-25}{357}\\{0}\\\cfrac{-257}{357}\\{0}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$a=\cfrac{-25}{357}$$$$b=0$$$$c=\cfrac{-257}{357}\\d=0$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the information.

Comment: The method you applied is correct. I didn't check the calculations.

Comment: @Berci I used the online matrix calculator to get the coefficient for a, b, c and d, I'm just curious if I entered the numbers from A in the correct matrix form as seen on B?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix